# polymorphism and inheritance in hibernate and mysql

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

In a spring mvc app using hibernate over MySQL, I am encountering problems when I try to create polymorphic subclasses that inherit their `id` from a `BaseEntity`.  You can see my intended use when you read my `AccessLog` class below, which has properties of type `BaseEntity`.  The `actor_entity` and `target_entity` properties should each be fillable with a variety of different types of entities, such as `User`, `OutsideSystem`, `Document`, etc., each of which inherit from `BaseEntity`.

How do I set this up in code?

Here is my current java:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class BaseEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    protected Integer id;
    //other stuff
}

@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class User extends BaseEntity{
    //other stuff
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "accesslogs")
public class AccessLog extends BaseEntity{

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "actorentity_id")
    private BaseEntity actor_entity;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "targetentity_id")
    private BaseEntity target_entity;

    @Column(name="action_code")
    private String action;
}
```

Here is my current DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS baseentity(
  id int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
)engine=InnoDB;SHOW WARNINGS;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS accesslogs(
  id int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  actorentity_id int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  targetentity_id int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  action_code varchar(100),
  access_date DATETIME
)engine=InnoDB;SHOW WARNINGS;

CREATE TABLE roles (
  id int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  role varchar(20) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE users (
  id int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  login varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  password varchar(20) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE user_roles (
  user_id int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  role_id int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  KEY user (user_id),
  KEY role (role_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need BaseEntity annotate with Entity? You don't need to specify @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED). BaseEntity should have @MappedSuperclass annotation

And you don't need to create baseentity table

Comment: `AccessLog` requires `BaseEntity` to have `@Entity` annotation because the `actor_entity` and `target_entity` both are of type `BaseEntity`.  `actor_entity` might have subtypes `User`, `Document`, `ExternalSystem`, etc.  When I try using `@MappedSuperClass` annotation for `BaseEntity`, the `actor_entity` and `target_entity` properties of `AccessLog` do not work.  How does this change your answer?

Comment: If I correctly understand, then you need to assign specific role to User, and have only one entity with list of Roles

Comment: If I take that approach, then `AccessLog` would have to include separate properties for `actor_user`, `actor_document`, `actor_externalsystem`, etc instead of the generic `actor_entity` property.  This would also require multiple redundant columns in the underlying data table.  And each of those entity types would need a separate entity with a list of `Roles`.  This would get very complicated.  I am trying to use inheritance and polymorphism to avoid the complexity. Also, the `User`, `Document`, and `ExternalSystem` entities need other functionality that they can use in other parts of the app

Comment: What is the purpose of AccessLog?

Comment: `AccessLog` is one example of many types of classes that need to track the activities of a variety of other types of classes.  We have polymorphism so that we can fit different types of things in a variety of different types of processes.  I just don't know how hibernate needs polymorphism to be written in this situation.

Comment: Sorry, then I just can't understand your goals.

Comment: `AccessLog` tracks access to specific resources.  That access may be performed by a variety of different types of entities.  A `User` might access a resource.  But an external system might also access the same resource.  These are handled by `actor_entity` property.  Similarly, there are many types of resources, which are tracked by `target_entity`.  A `user` might access an `address`, a `phone number`, a `name`, an `appointment note`, etc.  All those types of resources would need their own properties in the `AccessLog` entity. I try to avoid complexity using polymorphism.  Does this clarify?